# how to Pass Variable inside Autotable jsPDF

Tags: javascript, php, jspdf

Hello I am trying to pass variables from php into javascript jsPDF autotable:

```
function demoFromHTML() {
    var columns = [
    {title: "Producto", dataKey: "producto"},
    {title: "Fecha", dataKey: "fecha"}];
var rows = [
    {"producto": <?php echo $k34; ?>, "fecha": "text"}];
```

So far no result, the script is not working at all this way, any help will be very welcome.

Comment: maby  **demoFromHTML($k34)** pass variables to the function?

Comment: remember PHP runs at the server, and its done before the code hits the client's browser.  (1) what are you seeing in chrome dev tools for the line var rows = [{ ... ?   In the PHP code, what is value of $k34?    (2) what does jspdf have to do with anything?  (is that the right library?  I use jsPDF to convert PDF content --> Canvas --> PDF as appropriate...)

Comment: er wait.. are you talking about using this library?  https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable

Comment: wll the script is executed when the button download is pressed. with the php code inside nothing is downloading.  for this like I only see ;  nothing else.

Comment: yes this is the library

Comment: ok zipzit your hint about the check the code for this variable made it work! thank you.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad you are happy.  Just remember all the PHP stuff is executed at the server.  JavaScript is executed at the browser in front of the user.

Answer (score 0):

The jspdf-autotable library can either take html as input (using the doc.autoTableHtmlToJson() method) or a raw javascript object. The html method might be preferable if everything else in your application is written in php. If you want to use javascript you can convert data from php to javascript like this.

```
<script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>
```